# Why "Missing Control Sequence Inserted" using Pop Function on Token Register?

Tags: tex-core, token-lists

When using the `\Pop` macro from from [TeX by Topic](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPuIDB1JTZAhWKAcAKHbQwBPEQFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftex.loria.fr%2Fgeneral%2Ftexbytopic.pdf&usg=AOvVaw19yGhTWqNUY-umeiG6VlAm) chapter "Operations on token lists: stack macros", I get `Missing control sequence inserted`. Why? I copied it exactly as is! Was there a typographical error in the book? Do my eyes deceive me?

[image]

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex


\newtoks\tokenlist% initialize a token register


% Token List Functions
\def\Prepend#1#2{\toks0={#1}%
  \edef\act{\noexpand#2={\the\toks0 \the#2}}%
  \act}

\def\Pop#1#2{%
  \edef\act{\noexpand\SplitOff\the#1%
    \noexpand#2\noexpand#1}%
    \act}

\def\SplitOff#1#2#3#4{%
  \def#3{#1}#4={#2}}


% Add some tokens
\Prepend{{a}}{\tokenlist}% WORKS
\Prepend{{b}}{\tokenlist}% WORKS
\Prepend{{c}}{\tokenlist}% WORKS

\Pop{\tokenlist}{\front}

\showthe\tokenlist

\begin{document}
\null
\end{document}
```

Comment: *I copied it exactly as is!* — But you haven't, have you? The book's macros have things like `(into:)`, which yours don't.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR You are right. I thought those were comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tokens `(head:)`, `(tail:)`, `(to:)` and `(into:)` are *essential* parts of the syntax. If you omit them the macro will definitely not work.

The definitions in the book are

```
\def\Prepend#1(to:)#2{\toks0={#1}%
    \edef\act{\noexpand#2={\the\toks0 \the#2}}%
    \act}
\def\Pop#1(into:)#2{%
    \edef\act{\noexpand\SplitOff\the#1%
              (head:)\noexpand#2(tail:)\noexpand#1}%
    \act}
\def\SplitOff#1#2(head:)#3(tail:)#4{\def#3{#1}#4={#2}}
```

and they assume that the strings `(head:)`, `(tail:)`, `(to:)` and `(into:)` will never appear in the token lists you're managing.

Your definition of `\Prepend` only works for a single token, but `\Pop` and `\SplitOff` are completely wrong.

If I change `\act` into `\show\act` in the definition of `\Pop`, TeX prints

```
\SplitOff {c}{b}{a}\front \tokenlist
```

whereas TeX requires a control sequence to be at argument `#3`. Let's see what happens with Eijkhout’s definitions (again with `\show\act` for debugging):

```
\def\Prepend#1(to:)#2{\toks0={#1}%
    \edef\act{\noexpand#2={\the\toks0 \the#2}}%
    \act}
\def\Pop#1(into:)#2{%
    \edef\act{\noexpand\SplitOff\the#1%
              (head:)\noexpand#2(tail:)\noexpand#1}%
    \show\act}
\def\SplitOff#1#2(head:)#3(tail:)#4{\def#3{#1}#4={#2}}

\newtoks\tokenlist

% Add some tokens
\Prepend a(to:)\tokenlist
\Prepend b(to:)\tokenlist
\Prepend c(to:)\tokenlist

\Pop\tokenlist(into:)\front
```

We get:

```
> \act=macro:
->\SplitOff cba(head:)\front (tail:)\tokenlist .
```

which fits in the syntax of `\Splitoff`: argument `#1` is `c`, argument `#2` is `ba` and argument `#3` is `\front`.

Of course this can be more easily done with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definetl}{m}
 {
  \tl_new:N #1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\prepend}{mm}
 {
  \tl_put_left:Nn #2 { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\pop}{mm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx #2 { \tl_head:N #1 }
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \tl_tail:N #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definetl\tokenlist

% Add some tokens
\prepend{a}\tokenlist
\prepend{b}\tokenlist
\prepend{c}\tokenlist

\begin{document}

\pop\tokenlist\front

\verb|\front| $\to$ \front

\verb|\tokenlist| $\to$ \tokenlist

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I mistakenly thought those tokens (head, tail etc.) were comments!

Comment: @JonathanKomar No, they're argument delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably redundant and straightforward, but in case it's of any help, an explanation of the macros from the book:

```
\def\Prepend#1(to:)#2{\toks0={#1}%
    \edef\act{\noexpand#2={\the\toks0 \the#2}}%
    \act}
```

This defines `\Prepend` as something that first scans everything until the string `(to:)` as #1 and the next token as #2. In other words, when TeX encounters `\Prepend`, it will scan until it finds the five tokens `(`, `t`, `o`, `:`, `)` in that order — all earlier tokens are #1, and the first token after that is #2.

All these tokens are replaced by the definition of `\Prepend`, which leads TeX to first stored the `#1` tokens in `\toks0`, then define `\act`, then encounter `\act` and expand it.

For example if `#2` was `\mytokenlist`, then `\act` would be defined as “`\mytokenlist = {\the\toks0 \the\mytokenlist}`” except with both `\the` expressions replaced by the actual contents of `\toks0` and `\mytokenlist` respectively. You can see how this effectively prepends `#1` to `\mytokenlist`.

---

```
\def\SplitOff#1#2(head:)#3(tail:)#4{\def#3{#1}#4={#2}}
```

This defines `\SplitOff` as a macro that when TeX encounters, it scans the first token as `#1`, everything after that until the literal string `(head:)` as `#2`, everything after that until `(tail:)` as `#3`, and the token after that as `#4`. Then it replaces all of these with the definition of `\SplitOff`, which causes it to define `#3` (as `#1`) and set `#4` (to `#2`).

For example, with

```
\SplitOff lots of tokens here(head:)\dest(tail:)\mytokenlist
```

TeX would set `#1` to `l`, then `#2` to `ots of tokens here`, then `#3` to `\dest`, and `#4` to `\mytokenlist`. Everything will then be replaced with:

```
\def\dest{l}\mytokenlist={ots of tokens here}
```

so you can see that the effect is to pull out the `l` from `lots of tokens here` into `\dest`, and put the rest into `\mytokenlist`.

---

Finally,

```
\def\Pop#1(into:)#2{%
    \edef\act{\noexpand\SplitOff\the#1%
              (head:)\noexpand#2(tail:)\noexpand#1}%
    \act}
```

— this simply uses the above `\SplitOff` macro.

For example, if `\mytokenlist` contains `lots of tokens here`, then `\Pop\mytokenlist(into:)\dest` first defines `\act` as

```
\SplitOff lots of tokens here(head:)\dest(tail:)\mytokenlist
```

which as we saw earlier splits off the `l` from `\mytokenlist` into `\dest` and sets `\mytokenlist` to the rest, which is what `\Pop` is supposed to do.